# how to insert the masterdetails field in controller salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

Here in stud Sobject there are two master_deatils i.e course and trainer name. I need to insert the data. But not able to insert.Please help me...Thaks In Advance..

<apex:page controller="insert_cc_Class">
<apex:form >

```
 <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
     <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!save}"/>
     <apex:commandButton value="CANCEL" action="{!cancel}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
     
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Student Details">
     
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Student Name"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!Sname}" />
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
     
       
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Contact Number"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!Snumber}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
       
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Course Name"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!SCourseName}" />
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
      
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
       <apex:outputLabel value="Trainer Name"/>
       <apex:inputText value="{!trainername}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
      
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Date Of Birth"/>
         <apex:inputText value="{!dob}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
     
     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Qualification"/>
        <apex:selectList size="1">
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="B-Tech" />
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Diploma" />
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Graduate" />
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="MBA" />
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="MCA" />
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="PG" />
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="PHD" />
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Under Graduate" />
      </apex:selectList>
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
          
     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="State"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!state}"/> 
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
     
     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
       <apex:outputLabel value="City"/>
       <apex:inputText value="{!city}"/> 
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
     
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

</apex:form>
</apex:page>

public class insert_cc_Class {

// private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

```
public String city { get; set; }

public String state { get; set; }

public String qualification { get; set; }

public integer dob { get; set; }

public String trainername { get; set; }

public String SCourseName { get; set; }

public integer Snumber { get; set; }

public String Sname { get; set; }

public PageReference cancel() {
    return null;
}
```

public PageReference save() {

```
Stud__C obj = new Stud__C();

     obj.Sname__c = Sname;
     obj.Contact_Number__c = String.valueOf(Snumber);
     obj.Qualification__c = qualification;
     obj.DOB__c = date.ValueOf(dob);
     obj.Course_Name__c = SCourseName;
     obj.Trainer_Name__c = trainername;
     obj.State__c = state;
     obj.City__c = city;
     
    Insert obj;
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this is very complicated way to do it. Do you really need all these "outputLabel, inputText" etc? It's simpler if you use apex:inputField (it'd magically know the field label and whether the field type is text/date/picklist) and it'd let you easily display lookups too.

There are rare situations when you can't do that (need to bypass SF profile field permissions) but it's in "I really know what I'm doing" category. And for these if you can't just display a lookup you need to hand-craft some search + autocomplete solution. There should be lots of examples on net how to create VF+apex search by name functionality.

That's really reiinventing the wheel though. Seriously, consider using `<apex:inputField>`

```
public class Stack72386167{

    public Contact con {get;set;}
    
    public Stack72386167(){
        con = new Contact();
    }
    
    public void save(){
        insert con;
    }
}

<apex:page controller="Stack72386167">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Salutation}" /> <!-- picklists -->
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.FirstName}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.LastName}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.AccountId}" />  <!-- lookups
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Birthdate}" />  <!-- dates (and of course right field labels picked for "free", admin can change them without code changes -->
            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Is this working for Custom controller? <apex:inputField > normally use in Standard controller.

Comment: yes, it doesn't care. it needs an sObject to bind to, whether you got it from stdController.getRecord or from simply calling "new Stud__c()" or what. give me few min

Comment: If I write <apex:inputField>, then the error is comming, This is working in standard controller. Its is not working in Custom controller. please advise!!!  Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!Student Name" /><apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

Comment: Make public class-level variable `public Stud__C obj {get;set;}`. In controller initialise it, `obj = new Stud__C();`. And bind in VF `{!obj.Sname__c}`